# How do I use the Get Data function / From File / From Sharepoint folder within Excel?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services

What I am wanting to do is link up to 4 different workbooks together that we have on our company sharepoint. The problem is I have not been able to find a way to link workbooks together in sharepoint online. The reason we need this is to populate different fields on one workbook with data based on the other workbooks.

I thought that maybe I could do something with using the get data function to reference somehow back to the excel worksheet that we need the data on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've tested with Data > Get Data > From File > From SharePoint Folder and it seems to give me a sheet of the documents in my SharePoint Online site instead of a specific workbook.

However, if you can sync a document library to OneDrive for Business and get access to it on your local drive, you can connect to the specific Excel file via Data > Get Data > From File > From Workbook.

References:

[Connect to another workbook.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-another-workbook-3a557ddb-70f3-400b-b48c-0c86ce62b4f5)

[Import data from external data sources (Power Query).](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a)

Comment: Since it gives you a sheet of documents, and not a specific workbook, when you tested, not sure even if it gave you a workbook that it would solve the issue. Thoughts on FileCloud or Azure? Maybe a simple quick hosted server using Azure might be the best solution here?

Comment: If we use OneDrive for Business, does that mean all 24 users would need OneDrive for Business on their machines? But we would not be able to do anything permission wise correct?

Comment: @nothere1 I’m not familiar with Azure server but you can give it a try. Every user who has access to OneDrive for Business will have to manually sync the document library to their local machine, which means they cannot sync the document libraries they don’t permission with.

Comment: Egnyte is the answer to this problem, it allowed me to easily map a network drive, in which housed the excel documents so the links would work.